# Ampersand in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

When I set the Text property of RolesTextName from codebehind in a Silverlight5 app by doing:

```
RolesTextName.Text = "David &amp; Goliath";


<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <Span FontWeight="Bold">Roles:</Span>
        <Span><Run x:Name="RolesTextName" /></Span>
</TextBlock>
```

Problem: I don't get the & symbol, just the actual text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is used to create an object graph that represents your user interface. When you modify the user interface by setting property values in code the XAML has already been processed and is no longer used. You should not do any XAML specific encoding when modifying the object graph from code. Encoding is only required in XAML because it is based on XML and you need a way to represents characters like `&`, `<` and `>` unambgiously.

So executing

```
RolesTextName.Text = "David &amp; Goliath";
```

will set the text of the run to

```
David &amp; Goliath
```

To achieve what you want simply execute this code insted:

```
RolesTextName.Text = "David & Goliath";
```

Comment: Ahh thanks.  Turns out my stored proc was returning the &amp; instead of the symbol due to using XML PATH.  Workaround here:  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi im also quite new to XML, but I've had a similar problem in the past

This link gave me some insight, hope it can help you.

```
`<![CDATA[Wake & Bake]]>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Thanks JP - although this more specifically XAML... I suspect something strange is going on as I'd expect this text set to work.